# Damped harmonic motion experiment, bad results but good statistics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, data-analysis

I've done an experiment with a pendulum swinging at very small angles. I added an object with the shape of a rectangle to it, to increase the air friction to create damped harmonic motion.
This is the formula given to use:

$$y(t)=Ae^{-γt}sin(ω_D*t+Φ)\tag{1}$$

Where $A$ is amplitude, $γ$ is a restraining factor that depends on the amount of air drag, $ω_D$ is the angular frequency with the air drag, $Φ$ is the phase.

I used a sonar with 0.001[m] and 0.0001[sec] resolution to measure $y(t)$. Then I plotted $γ$ 4 times, 1 for every rectangle size. These graphs had very low P-probability values.
Then I used the formula:

(2) $ω_D^2=ω_f^2-γ^2$

Where $ω_f$ is the angular frequency without friction. I plotted a linear fit to (2), so I would expect that if $y=a_0+a_1x$ then $a_1=-1$

But the result was -488. However, the fit was actually linear with these statistical values:

Chi-squared reduced = 1.2

P-probability = 0.3

I would expect some error but not that big, and not good statistical values if the result is bad. Also, $ω_f$ was close to theory.  How does that make sense?

[image: linear fit by formula (2)]

Comment: I recommend attaching the plot. Would help us understand exactly what you did and it would help us identify any errors.

Comment: How did you calculate $\gamma^2$? What units does it have?

Comment: The software calculates $γ^2$ by fitting the sonar results to formula (1).  The $y(t)$ graphs have very small P-probability values.

Comment: What were the values of the amplitude and for how long did you run each experiment?

Comment: I ran it until the sine stopped decaying, which is 60-100 sec depending on which rectangle. The amplitudes were 0.0273, 0.0297, 0.0315, 0.0273 cm

Comment: *I ran it until the sine stopped decaying,* Does that mean that oscillations continued but with no noticeable decay of oscillations stopped?  What is the significance of the given amplitudes, start, finish??